# Getting root directory in angular for linking to any deeply-placed file

Tags: angular

I frequently require to link image files in html's present in folders at different levels, but my 'img' directory from where images are coming, is placed in 'src/assets'. Is there any way to get root ('/src'), so i can use that in html present at any level, like:

```
img src="{{root_dir}}+ '/assets/img/image.png' " />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can just declare a constant variable in a common shared file like `const root_dir= '../..'`
 And you can use like `<img src="`${root_dir}`+ /assets/img/image.png " />`

Answer (score -1):

https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config

if you are using  angular 2+ then you can direct us this

```
<img src="assets/logo.png

<img src="assets/img/image.png" />
```

or you want to user that way then try this

```
<img src=" `${root_dir}`+ /assets/img/image.png " />
```

or If you Want use any outside folder then

```
/outsideDirectory
    Img.jpg
/myProject
    /node_modules
    /src
    /Image
      - newImg.png
    .angular-cli.json
```

In your cli.json you can define the glob

```
"assets": [
    {"glob": "**/*", "input": "../../outsideDirectory", "output": "./assets/"}
]

"assets": [
    {"glob": "**/*", "input": "../Image", "output": "./assets/"}
]
```

This will copy the contents of your outsideDirectory or Image to the /dist/assets/ directory. Now you can use the image within your code

`<img src="assets/testImg.jpg">`
`<img src="assets/newImg.png.jpg">`